# showing utf-8 character in chart generated by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode-string

I want to use the symbol (u+2265):

[image]

in the y-axis label of my chart. How can I do that? Thanks.

#### UPDATE 01

I need to use add a `>=95` in the y-axis label, showing the group of people aged more than 95, I tried `expression(>=95)` but fail as it seems to expect something before `>=`. What can I do?

Comment: thanks for the answers, but seems they don't quite suit my need. Finally I used the Character Map in Windows and copy and paste the symbol, and it's done. But this comes to me another question, which I will post it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qplot(1, 1, ylab=expression(phantom(.) >= 95))
```

By using `phantom` in the expression, you don't get anything printed.  I put a period in there because `phantom` still leaves space, so I wanted something small.

Comment: @DWin, Ah, I didn't even think of the blank string.  Of course that is better than `phantom(.)`.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In the y-axis or label?

```
plot(1,1, ylab = expression(X >= 5))
```

Try `?expression` and `?plotmath`.

Comment: in the label, i tried expression, but how can I do it in ggplot2 chart?

Comment: the syntax here with `ylab = expression(...`, etc. works in ggplot.

Comment: and again, check the help on `expression()` and `plotmath` where you would have found `phantom()`... which wasn't part of the question when I answered.