# use of mathematical annotation as factor in R

Tags: r, expression, r-factor

I refer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508754/showing-utf-8-character-in-chart-generated-by-ggplot2), and want to know more about characteristics of `factor` in R.

Let say I have a dataset like this:

```
temp <- data.frame(x=letters[1:5],
                   y=1:5)
plot(temp)
```

I can change the label of `x` easily to another character:

```
levels(temp[,"x"]) <- letters[6:10]
```

But if I want to change it into some `expression`

```
levels(temp[,"x"]) <- c(expression(x>=1),
                        expression(x>=2),
                        expression(x>=3),
                        expression(x>=4),
                        expression(x>=5))
```

The `>=` sign will  not change accordingly in the plot. And I found that `class(levels(temp[,"x"]))` is `character`, but `expression(x>=1)` is not.

If I want to add some mathematical annotation as factor, what can I do?

Comment: `plot(temp)` does not plot for me in that example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any levels arguments in ggplot and assigning `levels` to a character vector should not work. If you are trying to assign expression vectors you should just use one `expression` call and separate the arguments by commas and you should use the labels argument in a scale function:

```
 p <- qplot(1:10, 10:1)+ scale_y_continuous( breaks= 1:10, 
                            labels=expression( x>= 1, x>=2, x>=3, x>= 4,x>=5,
                                              x>= 6, x>=7, x>= 8,x>=9, x>= 10) )
 p
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would just leave them as character strings

```
levels(temp[,"x"]) <- paste("x>=", 1:5, sep="")
```

If you then want to include them as axis labels, you could do something like the following to convert them to expressions:

```
lev.as.expr <- parse(text=levels(temp[,"x"]))
```

For your plot, you could then do:

```
plot(temp, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=1:5, labels=lev.as.expr)
```

Comment: (Tried to edit but missed my 5 min window 'cuz I took time to test.) Thanks for the new way to move across levels of abstraction. The way I already knew was : `labels=bquote(.(levels(temp[,"x"]) ))`

Answer (score 0):

Expression is used to generate text for plots and output but can't be the variable names per se.  You'd have to use the `axis()` command to generate your own labels.  Because it can evaluate expressions you could try...

```
plot(temp, xaxt = 'n')
s <- paste('x>', 1:5, sep = '=')
axis(1, 1:5, parse(text = s))
```